# How to plot the 'back-to-home-city-path' in TSA without repeating cities

Tags: graphs, artificial-intelligence, traveling-salesman, genetic-algorithms

I'm doing an implementation of the traveling salesman problem using genetic algorithms, but I can't get it: If we need to get the best route in a certain set of cities and then go back to the first city, how can we do that without going through cities we've already been through again? What would this route look like? I cannot understand the expected behavior in this case. How should my program behave? Which route should it return? How cost/distance should be calculated?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Asking how to find the best route through a set of cities without repeating any city is asking how to solve the travelling salesman problem, which we already know (or suspect) is likely to be hard to solve.  I don't know how to answer "How should my program behave?" - you are the one writing the program, that is for you to decide what you want it to do.

Comment: Have you played with https://tspvis.com/?